# Where does Magento store the PRODUCT_HAS_WEIGHT attribute

Tags: magento-2.1, product, database, attributes

For some of our configured products (unfortunately), the `PRODUCT_HAS_WEIGHT` attribute has not been set to `1`. Although, the products all have weight set (as a float), Magento still refuses to provide shipping calculation for these products.

I want to modify the `PRODUCT_HAS_WEIGHT` property for all products in the database. For that I want to access the MySQL database and issue a query that updates all the corresponding fields. Unfortunately, I was unsuccessful in identifying the attribute to update.

For example, to examine the weights, I would do the following:

1. `USE database`
2. `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code LIKE '%weight%'`
3. `SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal where attribute_id = 82`

In a similar fashion as in line (2), `product has weight` is not found.

I'd kindly ask the community, to help me find the related attribute to update for each product.

I'm using Magento CE 2.1.6.

Comment: Magento version ?

Comment: what is the magento version you are using

Comment: I'm using Magento CE 2.1.6. Sorry for missing out this important detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute is not stored, is only use for meta purposes by the repo and it is basically a wrapper for the weight attribute within the method `customizeWeightField()` of class `Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/General.php`

Modifying the product_has_weight you will change the product type; it defaults to `'Virtual'` but it will get converted to `"Download"` if it has downloadable data, remember that 'has' is a magic method prefix, although `hasWeight` is overridden on product types virtual and downloadable for the purpose of locking down a `false` Boolean value. The value is not specifically stored, the state will remain in the form of the product type, see the `TypeTransitionManager` class and the plugin `Magento\Downloadable\Model\Product\TypeTransitionManager\Plugin\Downloadable`, on configurable products it will be determined by the sum of the children state specified by the meta modifier.

Comment: when you say attribute, do you refer to the `has weight`? It is definitely stored somewhere, since it is switchable through the UI and for half of the products in the catalog, it prohibits shipping calculation at checkout. Do you know where can I find it and update through SQL?

Comment: I agree with his answer, and to me it seems the array key for example is modified when sent over the api (however I'm only guessing and will try to confirm now).

Comment: Thanks! However, it is still not clear to me, how should I update this attribute? I mean I can confirm from the Magento Admin, that some configured products have weight set, for example `1.5` kilograms, but the `has weight` is disabled. The `has weight` can be enabled. The state is preserved.

Comment: I have modified the answer to explain how has weight is determined

Comment: @Goku thanks, but I am having difficulties understanding it. All my products are `Configurable` or `Virtual` types. `Virtual` products for example are different sizes of certain apparel. How would you update the database with an SQL to enable "has weight" for all products? So if I happen to modify "has weight" of a product, that would just change the product type? I've just checked and half of my products are `Simple`. So they turn to simple if you modify the "has weight"? Should I just change everything to simple then?

Comment: It just happen that I've found a related post on one of the threads: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98898/converting-virtual-products-in-magento-2

Comment: I think the solution is to set all virtual products to simple using a DB update.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the constant for the property you are referring to, I haven't been using the API or repositories very much so I haven't seen the attribute before today:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/ProductAttributeInterface.php

The "weight" code attribute is mentioned in this file but only to update, not add.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Setup/InstallData.php

Unfortunately I haven't got a Magento instance set up at the moment, but my first (perhaps stupid) thought is to check catalog/product eav attributes?

Comment: thanks. I've found the `PRODUCT_HAS_WEIGHT` as well, but could not figure out how it hits the database. Ultimately, I'm looking for a SQL `UPDATE` command to set  `has weight` to true for all products in the catalog. I was unsuccessful in finding it in EAV attributes. Do you have any ideas in mind how to find it?

Comment: Weight is definitely in the eav_attribute table in Magento 2.1.4, I'm looking at it now. In my install it is attribute_id 82 however this could be different in yours?

From my experience I've never set anything to "has weight" it's either virtual or not, and then either has a weight > 0 or weight === 0...

Forgive my inexperience.

Comment: PRODUCT_HAS_WEIGHT does not appear in a search of all files in 2.1.4 whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to modify the PRODUCT_HAS_WEIGHT property for all products in the database. For that I want to access the MySQL database and issue a query that updates all the corresponding fields

As I needed this today and didn't find the accepted answer actually provided this, I have prepared the following one liner tested with Magento 2.3.3:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity cpe
SET type_id = IF(
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM catalog_product_relation WHERE parent_id = cpe.entity_id), 
    'configurable', 
    'simple'
)
WHERE type_id = 'virtual'
```

Note I am testing if there are child products so as to correctly identify configurable products, else their child products would be orphaned.