# How to get product_has_weight field value in frontend with product object?

Tags: product, magento2.3, product-attribute

How can i get below product attribute value in frontend ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want this product detail page?

Comment: @aravind  yes even in product list page too

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182696/where-does-magento-store-the-product-has-weight-attribute#182998

Answer (score 0):

This is not a product attribute, it is only used to switch between virtual and simple/configurable product types.

If the product is virtual then this will be as your question shows, so you can use product type to determine this.